# Disk busy 101% all the time

Tags: linux, memory, disk-usage

I have an OpenNMS Linux server which is having poor disk performance. The machine is a EC2 inside a VPC. **atop** shows:

[image]

**iotop** shows:

[image]

How do I reduce the IO numbers and bring down the disk utilization??

**ionice** response:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-12-251-11:~$ sudo ionice -c3 -p $(pidof opennms)
ionice: option requires an argument -- 'p'

ionice - sets or gets process io scheduling class and priority.

Usage:
  ionice [OPTION] -p PID [PID...]
  ionice [OPTION] COMMAND

Options:
  -c, --class <class>   scheduling class name or number
                           0: none, 1: realtime, 2: best-effort, 3: idle
  -n, --classdata <num> scheduling class data
                           0-7 for realtime and best-effort classes
  -p, --pid=PID         view or modify already running process
  -t, --ignore          ignore failures
  -V, --version         output version information and exit
  -h, --help            display this help and exit
```

Comment: EC2 are not famous for I/O capabilities; nevertheless how many objects have you in your NMS? We have 3,000 objects in our Nagios, and not a single problem. What you have to have in mind is that you cannot do *all the probes* in a 5-minute window with that many objects.

Comment: i am guessing a DISK size increase may tweak this.. not sure though coz i have 2 other EC2 instances which run openNMS in diff region with 100gbs , while this instance is having 8gbs only

Comment: As a rule of thumb, it is better to have around 70% of the disk free.

Comment: yep. absolutely , I am gonna fix this and close this question when done

Comment: The **ionice** fail is telling you that the *-p* option needs parameters (PIDs in this case) but isn't seeing any.  That means that `pidof opennms` returned nothing, and that means `opennms` wasn't running at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `rrenice` from *Debian*'s ***pslist*** package.  Example, this sets the priority of `opennms` and its descendants to the lowest possible setting:

```
sudo rrenice 19 opennms
```

Or that's not available, use plain `renice`:

```
sudo renice -n 19 -p $(pidof opennms)
```

For disk hog programs, use `ionice`:

```
ionice -c3 -p $(pidof opennms)
```

*BTW*:  that `opennms` process shouldn't be that resource hungry.  Something's either buggy or hung there.

Comment: `ionice -c3 -p `pidof opennms` ` this doesn't work that ways.. shows me how to use

Comment: @NishantSingh, please check that both **ionice** and **pidof** exist.  Run: `which ionice pidof`

Comment: returns 

/usr/bin/ionice
/bin/pidof

Comment: how to know the process id of openNMS

Comment: @NishantSingh, that's what **pidof* does, see `man pidof`.   Anyway you have both *ionice* and *pidof*, so let's try one more time, without backticks:  `ionice -c3 -p $(pidof opennms)`

Comment: not working still...

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: response is updated in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38319/discussion-between-agc-and-nishant-singh).

Answer (score 1):

Those figures show a write-bound process, so the [cache tuning](https://www.opennms.org/wiki/Performance_tuning#Database_PostgreSQL_2) suggested by OpenNMS won't help.

However it could help if you sacrificed [durability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durability_%28database_systems%29).  If your OpenNMS dies, it doesn't really matter if the database shows it dying a few seconds earlier.  (This is unlike e.g. an email server, where clients are relying on at-least-once semantics).  You could lose configuration changes made immediately before a crash though; maybe just make sure you notice crashes, and check the system is still online after making config changes.  Try `synchronous_commit = off`.  By default, the window of durability loss is just 600ms.

If `synchronous_commit = off` has the desired effect, there's a possible alternative that doesn't sacrifice durability.  See `commit_delay`.  It seems to me that OpenNMS could work very well with that too.  You'd want to set a `commit_delay` on the order of the reciprocal of your observed IOPS.  Then I think you could increase `<poller-configuration threads=` if CPU (and RAM) utilization is still low.

Comment: where do i found the mentioned settings?

Comment: Somewhere under `/etc/postgresql`.  I don't know if there'll already be a file that sets them or not.  I think you can put them in any `.conf` file in the right directory.

Comment: And OpenNMS poller configuration is apparently called `poller-configuration.xml`.  https://www.opennms.org/wiki/Polling_Configuration_How-To